# If I leave a guild, do I lose my guild credits?

Tags: castle-clash

Castle Clash recently added guilds.

I joined a guild and donated 50 hero shards, netting me (and the guild) 50 guild credits.
If I leave the guild, or if the leader kicks me from it, will I lose my credits? Or will they be retained for me to spend once I join a new guild?

Answer (score 2):

You keep your credits towards purchase for flags. The guild keeps the donated credits toward resarch.

Answer (score 1):

They stay with your guild. Hence the donation

Comment: When you donate 50 shards, your guild gets 50 credits and you get 50 credits. It makes sense that the 50 credits that the guild got stays with the guild, I am asking about the 50 credits that *I* got to personally spend on flags and such.

Comment: @ken.ganong Actually, when you donate 50 shards, only the guild gets 50 credits. You don't personally get 50 credits.

Comment: @krikara I don't think that's right. When I buy a flag to use, it costs me one guild credit. The number of guild credits my guild has didn't change when I bought that flag, but now I only have 49 left to buy flags with.

Answer (score 0):

Once a player donates his shards to the guild, the guild first converts shards to credits 1:1. Then the guild owns those credits and can use them to purchase various guild upgrades or flags.

A player cannot withdraw guild credits. Once you donate the shards, it forever belongs to the guild. It isn't your credits for the guild, but rather the guild's credits for the guild to spend.

Only the leader has authority to spend guild credits.

If you leave, or get kicked from the guild, you do not get a refund on your shards.

UPDATE: If you leave your guild, and then rejoin it, you don't regain your previous donation counter. Everyone starts back at 0 when they join a guild, even if you are rejoining.

Answer (score -1):

No, if you leave (or are removed) from a guild, you will lose them...

When you joined a new guild you start over again.